# Can a pretrained Deep learning model of objects (chair, table) be used to do transfer learning and classify telecom equipment?

Tags: transfer-learning

I want to classify telecom devices: switches, routers, etc. 
I know that there are pre-trained model available online: https://github.com/tensorflow/models

- Will it be possible to use transfer learning using those? Or do I have to use a pre-trained model of telecom devices? My reasoning is that the algorithm learns "forms"
- Which pre-trained model will you recommend me to do transfer learning?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An intermediate solution would be to use a pre-trained image classification model such as [ResNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/image_classification), freeze the weights of a few initial layers and re-train on your dataset. That way the initial layers will serve as a feature extractor. This should work well as long as your data is similar to ImageNet (in terms of size, number and order of channels, preprocessing etc).